# How can we convert a callable into a runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, callable, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a class which implements the callable interface. I want to schedule a task for the class using scheduleAtFixedRate method of ScheduledExecutorService interface. However scheduleAtFixedRate needs a runnable object as a command which it can schedule.

Hence I need some way in which I can convert a callable to a runnable. I tried simple casting but that is not working.

SAMPLE CODE:

```
package org.study.threading.executorDemo;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class ScheduledExecutionTest implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("inside the call method");
        return null;
    }

}
public class ScheduledExecution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService sec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
        sec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledExecutionTest(), 5, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: does `implements Callable, Runnable` not work? I've never tried using both before.

Comment: The purpose of a `Callable` is to return a value.  Why would you return a value you want to discard at a fixed rate?

Comment: Putting @PeterLawrey's comment another way, what *do* you want to do with the value returned by the 'Callable`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
FutureTask task1 = new FutureTask(Callable<V> callable)
```

Now this task1 is runnable because:

1. `class FutureTask<V> implements RunnableFuture<V>`
2. `RunnableFuture<V> extends Runnable, Future<V>`

So from above two relations, task1 is runnable and can be used inside `Executor.execute(Runnable)` method

Comment: While FutureTask is a convenient way of obtaining a Runnable from a Callable, note that the JavaDoc for FutureTask specifies that the computation cannot be restarted once completed, meaning it is only valid to run once.  Given that the question is about supplying a Runnable to scheduleAtFixedRate, which attempts to run multiple times, FutureTask is not appropriate for this purpose, although it could be useful in other cases where only a single execution is required.  JavaDoc link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html

Comment: Neither a Callable nor a Runnable is a Future, for the latter allows for asynchronous execution and the others don't. The fact you can convert one to the other, doesn't mean you should mess up with them.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't really need the `Callable` to return anything useful, you can wrap a Callable as a Runnable

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Object o = callable.call();
            System.out.println("Returned " + o);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log exception or wrap it with a RuntimeException
        }
    }
};
```

or in Java 8

```
Runnable run = () -> {
    try {
        Object o = callable.call();
        System.out.println("Returned " + o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log exception or wrap it with a RuntimeException
    }
};
```

This is quite messy but it sounds like the Callable should have been a Runnable in the first place and you wouldn't have to do this.

Comment: Catching and discarding exceptions like that is very bad practice (https://www.quora.com/As-a-software-engineer-developer-or-programmer-what-code-made-you-think-you-cant-be-serious/answer/Marco-Brandizi, see the comments I exchanged with Mirko).

Answer (score 2):

The JDK has a util method for exactly this:

```
Runnable runnable = ..
Executors.callable(runnable);
```

Comment: this is exactly the opposite of what was asked

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like:

```
  final Callable<YourType> callable = ...; // Initialize Callable

  Runnable callableAsRunnable = () -> {
     try {
        callable.call();
     } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle the exception locally or throw a RuntimeException
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use future task , it implements both Runnable and callable , you dont need to change your code much.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem with converting from `Callable` to `Runnable` is wrapping the exception that a callable might throw.

The [NoException package](https://noexception.machinezoo.com/) by Machine Zoo is a great help with this:

```java
@Test
public void testCallableToRunnable ()
{
    boolean[] flag = { false };
    
    Callable<String> callable = () -> {
        flag[0] = true;
        return "Hello, World";
    };
    
    Runnable runnable = Exceptions.sneak ().runnable ( () -> callable.call () );
    
    runnable.run ();
    
    Assertions.assertTrue ( flag [ 0 ], "Callable not run!" );
}
```

`sneak()` tricks the compiler into believing there is no checked exceptions, but eventually such exceptions can be thrown and are correctly intercepted. The `Exceptions` class offers other options, such as wrapping a checked exception with a `RuntimeException`.

As other said, `Executors` has an helper to convert from `Runnable` to `Callable`. Also said by others, the reason why the other way around isn't provided by the JDK is that perhaps, you're doing it wrong: if the callable returns some result, maybe you should use it and if it might throw an exception, probably you shouldn't ignore it.